# Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils' not found

Tags: zend-framework2

I’m just starting with Zend framework, and setup Zend framework 2 tutorial on my local development server, and its working fine, after following the instructions on their website.

I then uploaded the directory structure of the zend framework  to the shared server I am using, and I am getting an error:

Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils' not found in /home/content/ … /zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php on line 150

Any suggestions  of what I’m missing? 
Thanks

Comment: are you using config cache for your project? like this `'config_cache_enabled' => true,`

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is that the PHP version run on the shared host is 5.3.24, and the php version required for Zend is >=5.3.3